# How to get a list of users in an Azure Devops project using an API or CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to know if there are any cli commands or rest api's to get the list of users in an Azure DevOps project. For example, In an organization if there are two projects "alpha" and "beta" with 10 users in each project. I able to get all the list of 20 users by cli or rest api's. But, how can I only get the list of users in "alpha" project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Sajeetharan

We can use the API with the variable `scopeDescriptor` to get the list of user in one project.

Steps:

[List all projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and get the "alpha" project ID.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

Get the one project scopeDescriptor via [Descriptors - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/descriptors/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{storageKey}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

[image]

**Note**: we need enter the "alpha" project ID to the field `storageKey` and then Copy the value of `value` to the `scopeDescriptor` field of the API shared below.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Then we could only get the list of users in "alpha" project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [Azure Devops REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

you just need to set the scope with the project name.

> GET
> [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes={subjectTypes}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes=%7BsubjectTypes%7D&continuationToken=%7BcontinuationToken%7D&scopeDescriptor=%7BscopeDescriptor%7D&api-version=6.0-preview.1)

Comment: It's also important to remember about proper permissions assigned to your service account which will reach API.

Comment: pay attention, Graph work only on Azure DevOps Service, not on Azure DevOps Server